# How to async read from a file in Nim?

Tags: nim-lang

I was following the book Nim in Action.

In Chapter 3, there was an example like this:

```
import asyncdispatch, asyncfile

proc readFiles() {.async.} =
    var file = openAsync("/tmp/hello.py", fmReadWrite)
    let data = await file.readAll()
    echo(data)
    await file.write("Hello!\n")
    file.close()

waitFor readFiles()
```

The only change I've made to the example was replacing the file name with one that existed on my system.

The code was supposed to output the content of the opened file and write "Hello!\n" to it.

But when I ran it, the `readAll` always returned an empty string, which I verified by add `assert len(data) > 0`.

What can I change to do async read successfully?

**EDIT**:

The version of my `nim` compiler is:

```
$ nim --version
Nim Compiler Version 0.19.0 [MacOSX: amd64]
Compiled at 2018-09-28
Copyright (c) 2006-2018 by Andreas Rumpf

active boot switches: -d:release -d:useLinenoise
```

Answer (score 3):

So. The problem is you are assuming that `echo(data)` is supposed to print something. Even if you put data in this file to begin with, it never will print anything because, according to the [documentation](https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#fmReadWrite) for the `fmReadWrite` option:

> If the file does not exist it will be created. Existing files will be cleared!

Walk through this code, even with the async, it goes like this:

1. open a file (file is empty b/c fmReadWrite)
2. read the file
3. print the data you read
4. write hello\n to the file
5. close the file

Make sense?

The following code, taken straight from the [documentation](https://nim-lang.org/docs/asyncfile.html#openAsync%2Cstring) ...

```
import asyncfile, asyncdispatch, os

proc main() {.async.} =
  var file = openAsync(getTempDir() / "foobar.txt", fmReadWrite)
  await file.write("test")
  file.setFilePos(0)
  let data = await file.readAll()
  doAssert data == "test"
  file.close()

waitFor main()
```

... does exactly what you want. It is almost exactly the same as the book tutorial. Notice the `file.setFilePos(0)` call to reset your file pointer to the beginning after writing the data.

Also it should be noted, after reading this exact section in the book you're referring, the author doesn't say this should print anything out. They just say

> Displays the contents of the file.

I agree, it's a little misleading. I believe the point of the tutorial is to show you how easy it is to perform async I/O. Even though example code provided in the tutorial, does not print anything, but does leave you with a file containing `hello\n`.

Maybe a better example would be to create the file you want to read before you run the code, then change the flag to `fmReadWriteExisting`, that way, you will get something to print.